# echo hashed password for sudo command in multi system

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sudo, password

I want to make a shell that sends command which runs at sudo level,
from a system to multiple system.

for example:

```
for system in ${systems[@]}; do
    ssh $system "echo 'password' | sudo -S yum -y update python" > /dev/null > 2>&1 &
done
```

So the system that runs the shell will make other servers do the yum update.
Every system has the same sudo password.

But the password here is a plain text.
If I hash the password, it doesn't work since every system has different hash.

---

Question :
I want to hash a password in a shell that sends ssh command to other systems. How?

Comment: Use certificate based authentication to log in as root and avoid the issue entirely

Comment: I have certs. Still needs password since the shell doesn't run with root. It must be run at sudoer level because of SSO and SAC.

Comment: You should really consider using something like Ansible for things like these.

Comment: I really want to use Ansible, too. AWX is already installed, but I can't use it for the time being.

Comment: Is `yum -y update python` the only automated command your account needs to run as root?

Comment: Your question seems self-contradictory to me. "If I hash the password, it doesn't work" followed by "I want to hash a password..." Can you resolve that conundrum by editing your question to pick a direction? Thank you!

Comment: @roaima yes the shell will update whatever I set as parameters

Comment: @JeffSchaller I wanted them both. I thought there was a way and I didn't know cause I'm noob. I'm currently trying to work around with `read -sp` but can't think of a way to deal with wrong passwords.